# Will $S(\infty)$ lie on the same circle as that of $S(\mathbb R)$ for every Möbius transformation $S\ $?

Tags: complex-analysis, mobius-transformation, cross-ratio

> Let $S : \mathbb C_{\infty} \longrightarrow \mathbb C_{\infty}$ be a Möbius transformation. Does $S$ necessarily send $\infty$ to $\infty\ $?

I am actually following Conway's book on Complex Analysis. There I found a result which states as follows $:$

> Let $z_1,z_2,z_3$ and $z_4$ be four distinct points in $\mathbb C_{\infty}.$ Then $(z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4)$ is a real number iff all four points lie on a circle.

I understand that if we can somehow prove that every Möbius transformation sends $\mathbb R_{\infty}$ into a circle then we are through. But the author shows that every Möbius transformation  $S : C_{\infty} \longrightarrow \mathbb C_{\infty}$ sends every element of $\mathbb R$ to a circle  Here I have two doubts $:$

> $(1)$ Why do we consider straight lines as circles?
>
> $(2)$ Why is it enough to show that for any Möbius transformation $S$ that $S$ sends $\mathbb R$ to a circle? If we know that $S$ sends every element of $\mathbb R$ to a circle does it always imply that $S$ sends $\infty$ to the same circle?

Any suggestion in this regard will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: $S(z)=1/z$ sends $\infty$ to $0$. (1) You can see $\mathbb{C}_\infty$ as a sphere with an inclusion of $\mathbb{C}$ in it. This inclusion sends straight lines of $\mathbb{C}$ to circles in that sphere that pass through the point $\infty$. A property that they'll prove is that Moebius transformations map circles and lines of $\mathbb{C}$ to circles or lines.

Comment: (2) Any straight line in $\mathbb{C}$ can be sent to $\mathbb{R}$ by some invertible affine transformation $z\mapsto az+b$, with $a\neq0$. This, and its inverse, are Moebius transformations.

Comment: @plop I don't get your point. Can you please elaborate? Do you understand my question? I want to say that suppose I know that for any Möbius transformation $S$ the image of the real line lies on a circle. Does it also imply that $S(\mathbb R_{\infty})$ is a subset of the same circle?

Comment: Is $\mathbb{R}_\infty$ the union of $\mathbb{R}$ and $\infty$? If that is the case, note that Moebius transformations are continuous and circles are closed. Since $\infty$ is a limit point of $\mathbb{R}$ and $S(\mathbb{R})$ is in a circle, then $S(\infty)$ must be a limit point of $S(\mathbb{R})$. Since circles are closed, then the limit point must also be in the circle.

Comment: @plop Yes I mean that. For that I need to show that $S(\infty)$ lies on a same circle determined by $S(\mathbb R).$

Comment: @plop any open neighborhood around $\infty$ will be complement of a compact subset of $\mathbb R.$ Right? Because $\mathbb R_{\infty}$ is nothing but the one point compactification of $\mathbb R.$ Since $\mathbb R$ is non-compact any open neighborhood of $\infty$ must intersect $\mathbb R.$ That's why you are saying that $\infty$ is a limit point of $\mathbb R.$ Am I right?